# check if samba directory exist in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, samba, smb, pysmb

I have a samba directory smb://172.16.0.10/public_pictures/ and I would like to know if it is accessible.

try something like the following:

```
import urllib

if open("smb://172.16.0.10/public_pictures/"):
    print("accessible")
else:
    print("no accessible")
```

but obviously it does not work for me

Comment: take a look at pysmb https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

One way of handling samba is to use [`pysmb`](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  If so, then it goes something like the following:

```
# we need to provide localhost name to samba
hostname = socket.gethostname()
local_host = (hostname.split('.')[0] if hostname 
              else "SMB{:d}".format(os.getpid()))

# make a connection
cn = SMBConnection(
    <username>, <password>, local_host, <netbios_server_name>,
    domain=<domain>, use_ntlm_v2=<use_ntlm_v2>, 
    is_direct_tcp=<self.is_direct_tcp>)

# connect
if not cn.connect(<remote_host>, <remote_port>):
    raise IOError

# working connection ... to check if a directory exists, ask for its attrs
attrs = cn.getAttributes(<shared_folder_name>, <path>, timeout=30)
```

Some notes:

- in your example above, `public_pictures` is the `shared folder`, while `path` would be simply `/`
- you'll need to know if you are using SMB on port `139` or `445` (or a custom port).  If the latter you will usually want to pass `is_direct_tcp=True` (although some servers will still serve NetBIOS samba on `445`)
- if you expect not to need a username or password, then probably you are expecting to connect as `username="guest"` with an empty password.

Answer (score 0):

Using pysmb ([docs](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)):

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

remote_address = "172.16.0.10"
share_name = "public_pictures"

conn = SMBConnection(username, password, name, remote_name)
conn.connect(remote_address)

accessible = share_name in conn.listShares()
```

Comment: What if I do not use username and password?

Thank you

Comment: @laur then you will probably want to use `username="guest"`, `password=None` (and `domain=None`, which should be the default)